# How to import existing project to existing private github repository in intellij idea?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

how can I import my project to an existing private github repository using intelij idea please? the only option I can find is to create a new repository.

Thank you

Comment: If you already have have a repo locally I guess you are looking for `VCS->Import into Version Control->Share Project on Github`

Comment: Thank you, but "Share project on Github" allow me only to create a new repository, not choosing an existing one

Comment: Please follow the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40741742/how-should-i-add-my-intellij-project-to-an-already-existing-github-repository